# perl doing different things on two different platforms

Tags: perl, solaris

On Mac OSX, this works fine with perl

```
perl -v
This is perl, v5.8.9 built for darwin-2level
perl -e 'sub test {}'
```

But on Solaris

```
perl -v
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for i86pc-solaris-thread-multi
perl -e 'sub test {}'
Illegal declaration of anonymous subroutine at -e line 1.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Kelly

Comment: I guess perl -c 'sub test {}' gives the same error, right?

Comment: perl -c 'sub test {}'
Can't open perl script "sub": No such file or directory

Comment: He meant `perl -c -e'sub test {}'` (though I don't know why he's asking)

Comment: Possible workarounds: `perl -e'; sub test {}'` `perl -e'sub test {;}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely a behavior difference between the two versions of Perl. It's also probably just a bug in the CLI evaluation mode in 5.8.8

Try this test to see if it's just the CLI evaluation or Perl itself:

```
use strict;
sub test {}
```

If it passes strict mode in a file, it's probably as good as it's gonna get.

Comment: I updated to 5.12.3 and this seems to have corrected the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[`perldoc perldiag`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) says:

> - **Illegal declaration of anonymous subroutine**
>     (F) When using the sub keyword to construct an anonymous subroutine,
>     you must always specify a block of code. See [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)

It's could possibly be in a `sitecustomize.pl` file. It's *not* seeing the "test". It's reading it as `'sub'`. Try typing `perl -e 'test {}'` on the command line.

Also to take out the customization file, you could add the `-f` switch to the command line. `perl -fe 'sub test {}'

[`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for more information.

Comment: perl -e 'test {}' works but the -fe on the original does not.

Comment: @Kelly McDonald, I'm not thinking that 'test {}' should work. I don't have pre-5.12 handy anywhere at the moment.